# injecting settings resolved from IOption into additional class in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

How to inject Settings created from IOptions value to call some class method?

I have `MailAppSettings` class and `MailSender: IMailSender`. Both are in different .NET projects.

Values into `MailAppSettings` are loaded using `IOptions` pattern in .NET Core. Values are loaded from `appsettings.json` configuration. For DI we use AutoFac, so it looks like this:

```
 serviceCollection.AddOptions();
 serviceCollection.Configure<MailAppSettings>(config.GetSection("MailAppSettings"));
```

And later then we access `mailSettings` like this:

```
 public class CustomerSender:ICustomerSender
   {
        private readonly MailSettings _mailSettings;
        private readonly IMailSender _mailSender;

        public MyCustomerSender(IOptions<MailSettings> mailSettings, IMailSender mailSender)
        {
            _mailSettings = mailSettings.Value;
            _mailSender = mailSender;
        }

        public SomeCustomMethod1() {
        // use of mailsettings
            var recipient = mailSettings.Recipient1;
            var body = BuildSomeBody();
            var subject = mailSettings.Subject1;

            // mail sending
            _mailSender.Send(recipient, body, subject);
         }
```

`mailSender` is the class that sits in separate namespace and is called from different places in different projects.

```
    public class MailSender: IMailSender
    {
        private readonly IMailSenderSettings _mailSenderSettings;

        public MailSender(IMailSenderSettings confg) ///!!! here we need to inject those settings
        {
            _mailSenderSettings= confg;
        }
        ...
```

Here, you see that `mailSender` needs `IMailSenderSettings` to be injected.
`MailAppSettings` implements this interface (but also contains additional properties).

My question is- how to inject `MailAppSettings` into `IMailSenderSettings`?
If I just register type like this:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MailAppSettings>()
               .As<IMailSenderSettings>()
               .SingleInstance();
```

it won't work, values of injected IMailSenderSettings would be null.

`IMailSenderSettings`, as well as, `MailAppSettings` contains `recipient`, `smtp host,` `password`, `user`, but `MailAppSettings` also contains additional properties not needed for `IMailSenderSettings`

Comment: "because MailAppSettings values are set only in constructor in CustomerSender." -> it's not clear what you mean by this. Also, it doesn't matter what `MailSettings` has as long as it implements `IMailSenderSettings`

Comment: You will need to create `IMailSenderSettings`  derived class that depends on `MailSettings` so that the desired members can be mapped in the composition root. From there it is only a matter of registering the implementation so that the DI container can handle the rest.

Comment: @Nkosi can you please give me an example, I think I do not understand you...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I mean that if I do registration of DI as I did, in mailSender _mailSenderSettings values are all null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create `IMailSenderSettings` derived class that depends on `MailSettings`

```
public class MyMailSenderSettings: IMailSenderSettings {
    private readonly MailSettings mailSettings;

    public MyMailSenderSettings(IOptions<MailSettings> options) {
        this.mailSettings = options.Value;
    }

    public string SomeProperty => mailSettings.SomeMatchingProperty;

    //... other members mapped from settings 
}
```

so that the desired members can be mapped in the composition root.

From there it is only a matter of registering the implementation so that the DI container can handle the rest.

```
//...

serviceCollection.AddOptions();
serviceCollection.Configure<MailAppSettings>(config.GetSection("MailAppSettings"));

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMailSenderSettings, MyMailSenderSettings>()

//...
```